# JavaScript DOM tree diff

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, diff

I am auto generating an HTML page and would like to do a diff between the newly generated HTML page and a previously generated HTML page.

I want to do this by letting the user enter a the filename of the old HTML page into the new HTML page which will then load it as an IFRAME and do a diff on the DOM trees, modifying my current tree in order to display the results.

My page consists of a table, which has a subtable in each cell.

I am using JQuery.

Are there any existing tools/libraries that I should be using?

At the moment I'm working on implementing this myself but I'm sure someone else has already done this...

**Clarification:** I am not asking for diffs of text. I am asking for tools that can do a diff of DOM objects. Meaning, diffing the contents of HTML tables based on the contents of the tables them selves, text diff tools will not suffice.

Comment: https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462609/looking-for-a-javascript-visual-diff-lib. helpful to you

Comment: No, that diffs text and that won't do. I want to diff the contents (numerical values) inside an HTML table. Textual diffs wouldn't be enough.